# Source code for Layout Based Switcher in KDE?

Tags: 12.04, apt, kde, source-code

I want to take a look at the source code for the Layout Based Switcher. I know how to use `apt-get source <packagename>` to pull source, my problem is kde has an awful lot of packages, and I'm not sure in which one to look.

The Layout Based Switcher looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The layout based switcher is part the KDE Plasma workspace and is provided by the `kde-workspace` (source package)
- The technical name for the "layout based switcher" component is *TabBox*, and its source can be found inside the `kwin/tabbox` directory of the `kde-workspace` source.
- For more information, see this [KDE Dev Page](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KWin/WindowSwitcher)